# Is it necessary to consider $\epsilon$ when it come to strict inequality linearization?

Tags: integer-programming, linearization

My decisions variables are all binary. One the constraints I'd like to include into a model is in the from of $\sum_{(i,j) \in E}  \delta_{i,j}^t \ge 1 \implies \theta^t =1 \qquad \forall t$

I wanted reverse the statement and write it as    $\theta^t =0 \implies  \sum_{(i,j) \in E} \delta_{i,j}^t < 1  $ and this leads to introducing $\epsilon$ which I try to avoid. Is there any way to circumvent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a sum of integers, $<1$ is equivalent to $\le 0$.
You can enforce the indicator constraint
$$\theta^t =0 \implies  \sum_{(i,j) \in E} \delta_{i,j}^t \le 0$$
via linear big-M constraints
$$\sum_{(i,j) \in E} \delta_{i,j}^t \le |E| \theta^t. \tag1\label1$$
Because all variables are binary, you can obtain a stronger formulation by disaggregating \eqref{1} as follows:
$$\delta_{i,j}^t \le \theta^t \quad \text{for all $(i,j) \in E$}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Try:
$ M(\sum_{(i,j) \in E} \delta_{i,j}^t - 1) \le \theta^t - 1$
$ \theta^t \le M\sum_{(i,j) \in E} \delta_{i,j}^t $\